# Bad Gateway 502 on post request

Tags: docker, nginx, traefik

I had 2 dockers containers running. Static angular web app by nginx and nodeJS express. Both web app and express server is running fine. But when I call POST request, express server returns **502: Bad gateway**

List item

**(Web app) Nginx.conf**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

**(Web app) Docker**

```
FROM nginx:alpine
RUN rm /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY ./dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx"]
```

**(Express App) Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:10-alpine

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

EXPOSE 6644
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**Running web app container**

```
docker container run -d webapp  --network="traefik_proxy" -p 8888:80 
  --label "traefik.backend=shijieadmin-production"
  --label "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:web.domain.com"
  --label "traefik.enable=true"
  --label "traefik.port=80"
  --label "traefik.docker.network=traefik_proxy"
```

**Running express app container**

```
docker container run -d expressapp  --network="traefik_proxy" -p 6644:6644
--label "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:api.domain.com"
--label "traefik.enable=true"
--label "traefik.port=6644"
--label "traefik.docker.network=traefik_proxy"
```

Comment: Did you find a solution Henry?  Who was your cloud provider?